# Change resource file not on localisation

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment

I have a web site deployed for several customers.

For security reasons, the deployment is initiated from the target server. The deployment consist in copying the file to `dev->prod`.

For each target site, I have a specific resource file and at the deployment time I rename the file from `xxx.resx` to `Resource.resx`. This works fine but I wonder, if it is possible to define the resource file to use from the `web.config`?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

You can make a variable in web.config in which you can enter the name of the resx to use.
It should require you to access the resource object with [GetGlobalResourceObject(string, string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153593.aspx) though, assuming the resx file(s) are located in App_GlobalResources.

If you want intellisense, then you'd have to make sure all the .resx files have the exact same keys (cause the keys will be compiled) and then keep renaming. For example in Global.asax's Application_Start event, which is fired whenever the app starts/restarts.

Anyway, have a look at this for info on the web.config variable: http://forums.asp.net/t/1386667.aspx/1

Comment: Thank you, it is working but I wonder if it is possible to do a `SetGlobalResource` like.

Otherwise I will have to change numerous existing pages.

Comment: SetGlobalResource as in change the file used runtime? I don't know how to make it look good, but you can always do that rename-thing. I'm gonna have to ask if this is a language thing or not?